# Error handling in list of scala futures - Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, concurrency

I am having issues while handle exceptions in List of Scala futures. I am calling `getQC_report(qcArgsThread,spark)` method within `ruuner` method which process input file and saves in Hive table. Code below

```
  import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
  import scala.concurrent._
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("yarn").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
  
  var argsList: List[Array[String]] = List[Array[String]]()
  for(ip_file <- INPUT_FILE.asScala.toList) {
    var qcArgs:Array[String] = null
       qcArgs = Array("input_file", ip_file,
        "hiveDB",hiveDB,
        "Outputhive_table",Outputhive_table)
    argsList = qcArgs :: argsList
  }
  var pool = 0

  def poolId = {
    pool = pool + 1
    pool
  }

  def runner(qcArgsThread: Array[String]) = Future {
    sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", poolId.toString)
    getQC_report(qcArgsThread,spark)
    }
  val futures = argsList map(i => runner(i))

  futures foreach(f => Await.ready(f, Duration.Inf))

  futures.onComplete {
    case Success(x) => {
      println(s"\nresult = $x")
    }
    case Failure(e) => {
      System.err.println("Failure happened!")
      System.err.println(e.getMessage)
    }
  }
```

I am getting error in `futures.onComplete` line.

> Error - Cannot resolve symbol onComplete.

Please help me in improving the code as I am new to using Scala Futures. Thanks!

Comment: Alright... 1) Please remove `java.util.concurrent` tag. It's irrelevant 2) I highly recommend spending a few months with Scala before learning Spark. Most people who go straight to Spark end up miserable and not able code in either 3) DON'T EVER USE VARIABLES IN SPARK, they will blow up your entire program
4) Your program won't compile because `List` doesn't have a method named `onComplete` you will need to compose these Futures. One option is `Future.sequence`
5) Awaiting and `OnComplete` are redundant. Pick one

Comment: Some more suggestions. 1) Scala allows you to use `space` instead of `.` for method calls but don' t do that. 2) Spark is a platform with a Scala API, if you are not using any of the Spark features in your program then why use Spark at all ? 3) A Spark application should be implemented with Spark guidelines. You mostly don't want to mix Scala futures with Spark unless you have very good understanding of both.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments, i will improve the code based on the suggestions. I am using Spark features in `getQC_report`. In this method, i am processing large files and generating data profiling report.

Comment: Some more suggestions about using var (mutable variable). Not just in a Spark, in Scala as a functional programming paradigm you should try to avoid using var and use val (immutable) instead. This is to avoid 'side effect' which will help to prevent a lot of unexpected problems in application.

For me, the only place that you can use var is when you make some change to a mutable variable within some local scope only. (var pool in your example has side effect because it change outside def poolId scope) This way it'll guaranteed that the scope such as method still doesn't have any side effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that because `argsList` is a `List[Array[String]]`

```
val futures = argsList map(i => runner(i))
```

will have the type `List[Future[WhateverGetQC_ReportReturns]]`.  It specifically is not a `Future`, so has no `onComplete` method.

If you want to have a `Future` which completes when all the futures are completed, `Future.sequence` will convert a `List[Future[T]]` into a `Future[List[T]]`:

```
// replaces all code after val futures = argsList map ...
val allFutures = Future.sequence(futures)

val result: List[WhateverGetQC_ReportReturns] =
  try {
    Await.result(allFutures, Duration.Inf)
  } catch {
    case NonFatal(e) =>
      System.err.println("Failure happened!")
      System.err.println(e.getMessage)
  }
```